# Is there a keyboard shortcut to evaluate an expression in the Watch window in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

If you use a method call in an expression in the Watch Window, Visual Studio does not constantly evaluate the expression all the time and instead says

> This expression causes side effects and will not be evaluated

I appreciate the necessity for this, but every time that I *do* want to evaluate the expression, the only ways I’ve found so far are:

- Click the re-evaluate button — requires grabbing the mouse, yuck
- Edit the expression by adding a trailing space — clunky workaround

I already looked through the list of commands that I can assign keyboard shortcuts to, and the only relevant I found is *Debug.EvaluateStatement*, which sounds like it’s exactly what I need, but it doesn’t appear to have any effect.

**Is there a keyboard-assignable command to evaluate expressions in the Watch window?**

Comment: This is a bug. I have the same problem with certain constructs that have no side effects and have to use a space to get the expression recalculate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut required is <kbd>Space</kbd>. It is not a customisable command though.

Comment: +1 Useful! It would be nicer though if you could select a bunch of values in the watch window and evaluate them all at once. Know how to do that?